# How to detect a hot restart in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, bluetooth, hot-reload

I am trying to detect a **hot restart** in my **Flutter** app **programmatically**, so that I can **perform some actions before the app restarts**.

What I have tried:

```
WidgetsBinding.addPostFrameCallback method,
flutter_reload package, but it is not available anymore,
```

I have been able to detect a Hot Reload using this:

```
@override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    print("________________________________________________");
    print("The app is Reloading...");
    print("________________________________________________");
    if (user.equipment != null && user.equipment!.isConnected()) {
      print("Deconnecting blutooth device");
      user.equipment!.disconnectDevice();
      print("Disconnecting ended");
    }
  }
```

But it don't allow to detect Hot Restart.

I've found this GitHub [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29647) on Flutter official repo, the problem is closed since 2019, so I guess it has been added.

**Is there a way to detect a Hot Restart in Flutter?**

Please note that this need, is only intended for debugging purposes. However, during testing or demos, it is possible that testers may hit the hot restart button and think there is a bug because the app is unable to connect back to the Bluetooth equipment. In order to avoid confusion and ensure smooth testing, it is important to be able to disconnect when a hot restart occurs.

Thank you for your help and support.

Comment: When inside the main the equipment is already lost, so I cannot disconnect from it.